# Add 100px space to scrolltop

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery function to scroll to div IDs within a single page site:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var top = $('html').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: top},1500, 'easeInOutCubic');
    return false;
});
```

Is there a way to add 100 pixels of space above each div using jQuery?

I have a fixed position menu in the top of the browser window and need the divs to remain below the menu when scrolled to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if I got the question right, but it sounds very easy to achieve:

```
...
var top = $('html').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100;
...
```

Comment: `var href = $(this).attr('href');`
`var top = $('html').find(href).offset().top - (href !== '#top' ? 100 : 0);`